Как вывести динамическое поле в шаблон сайта
Подскажите как можно вывести поле из готовой темы шаблона сайта (в моем случае поле видео заполненное пользователем) в шаблон нужной страницы. Если бы я создавал это поле, например через ACF, тогда ясно как, но это поле кастомное созданное разработчиком темы.
upd: Тема у меня - https://motors.stylemixthemes.com/elementor-classified-one/

Если менеджер заполняет данное поле (ссылка на видео), хочу его выводить в шаблоне блоком видео. Думал воспользоваться Elementor Pro (поскольку тема построена данным конструктором) Для вывода динамических полей

Вероятно это мета поле, которое можно получить через get_post_meta(). Но не понятно две вещи, откуда тут elementor в метках (речь вообще про elementor?), ну и второе, если это уже готовая тема, то по идее вывод данного поля должен был быть уже предусмотрен.

Чтобы тебя понимали начни с освоения терминологии. +Давай больше конкретики - какая тема (ссылку на репо), что как делаешь и тд.

Обновил свой вопрос

По идее должно быть доступно через Dynamic Tags

Если поле создано с помощью плагина ACF и это просто поле для ссылки(URL), то вот код:
<a href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_field('sales_url') ); ?>">
<?php echo esc_attr( get_field('sales_url') ); ?>
</a>

В примере это поле называется 'sales_url' у вас может быть любое название на латинице без пробелов, вот инструкция:
Инструкция на сайте ACF

Так же можно создать кастомный Gutenberg Block и вывести поле в gutenberg блоке, вот пример как это делается с помощью кода и как это делается с помощью ACF:
инструкция от WebDevStudios

Уточню что блоки делать можно только в ACF Pro ее нужно покупать
Бесплатная альтернатива: carbonfields.net
Действуете следующем образом:

создаете поле для вашего типа записи
создаете кастомный gutenberg Block
добавляете поле ссылки в ранее созданный Gutenberg Block

Если определитесь с инструментами и скажите название поля могу прислать готовый код для вставки
